# Image not displaying using QPainter drawImage

Tags: qt

I have an QFrame within a QWidget, in my application. When I try to draw a draw a image within the QFrame, the image is inserted only when coordinates are (0,0) and if they are something like (100,100) the image is not drawn. I created a new class for the frame and implemented paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p) in it. Is there any thing I am doing here ?

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QFrame>
#include <QPainter>
#include "frame.h"

class frame;
namespace Ui {
    class Widget;
}
class Widget : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    frame * f;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QFrame(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    f = new frame(ui->frame);
    f->show();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

frame.h

```
#ifndef FRAME_H
#define FRAME_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>

class frame : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit frame(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // FRAME_H
```

frame.cpp

```
#include "frame.h"

frame::frame(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

}

void frame::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p)
{
    QPainter* pPainter = new QPainter(this);
    QImage img(":/left.png");
    Q_ASSERT(!img.isNull());
    QRect source(0,0,20,10);
    QRect target(50,50,20,10);
    pPainter->drawImage(target, img,source);
    QWidget::paintEvent(p);
    QWidget::update();
}
```

If I use QRect target(0,0,20,10) in the above code the image is drawn.

testImage.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testImage
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp \
    frame.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h \
    frame.h

FORMS    += widget.ui

RESOURCES += \
    src.qrc

DISTFILES +=
```

I am being stuck in this one for a long time, any idea will be helpful. I have tried Qt verions 5.6 and 5.8, similar result. And the OS is Lubuntu. The image resolution is 20*10. Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXcbM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
void frame::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p){
QPainter lPainter(this);
QPixmap lPixmap(":/left.png");
Q_ASSERT(!lPixmap.isNull());
QRect source(0,0,20,10);
QRect target(50,50,20,10);
lPainter->drawPixmap(target, lPixmap);
QWidget::paintEvent(p);}
```

remove update form painEvent and try to use pixmap.

Comment: I am getting the same result as before, But I have found a possible reason for the error. For target "QRect target(80,50,20,10)" row values from 0 to 80 the image is printed properly and from then on the image gets shrinked and at the end the image is not displayed when the row value reaches 100.

Comment: and what is the size of you widget you are trying to draw on?

Comment: Very interesting.

Comment: Are sure size of image is 20*10?

Comment: Yes. I have also found a issue, not sure if its causing the problem. If I implement the paintEvent function in the parent widget class (widget.cpp) I don't face any issue. But if I implement it in frame.cpp, widget's subclass, I face the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, I have subclassed QgraphicsView and reimplemented paint method in it,

```
void graphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
  QGraphicsView::paintEvent(e);
  QPainter pPainter(this->viewport());
  QImage img(":/images/x.png");
  Q_ASSERT(!img.isNull());
  QRect target(300,230,20,10);
  pPainter.drawImage(target, img);
}
```