# QPixmap resizing with Realsense image

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlabel, qpixmap

I try thanks to a Qlabel to make it automatically resizable, it includes a QPixmap which displays a Realsense camera that works on a thread `vid_thread` . I have a timer that refreshes the image every 20 milliseconds, to avoid too heavy load. Except that the resizing is not fluid, it does not instantly follow the movement of the mouse as do the other elements of the interface.

I tried thanks to resize event not to make it dependent on this timer, and since it's more fluid, but still not instantaneous

Any smart hints how to accomplish this ?

```
class UI_main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        [...]
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(20)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.setImage)
        self.timer.start()
        [...]
    def setImage(self):
        self.camLabel.setP(self.server_thread.vid_thread.p)
        [...]
    def setupUi(self):
        [...]
        self.camLabel = camLabel(self.detectionContainer)
        self.camLabel.setStyleSheet("border-color: rgb(112, 112, 112); border-width : 1px; border-radius:5px; border-style:inset;")
        self.hCamContainer.addWidget(self.camLabel)
        [...]

class camLabel(QLabel):
    mouseSignal = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(camLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.p = QPixmap()
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)
        self.setScaledContents(True)

    def setP(self, p):
        self.p = QPixmap.fromImage(p)
        self.setPixmap(self.p.scaled(self.width(), self.height(),
                                     Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.x=int(event.x()*(640/self.width()))
        self.y=int(event.y()*(480/self.height()))

        print("point x: ", self.x, ", point y: ", self.y)
        print("point x (ancien): ",event.x(), ", point y(ancien): ", event.y())
        print("Width : ", self.width(), ", Height: ", self.height())

        self.mouseSignal.emit((self.x,self.y))

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.setPixmap(self.p.scaled(self.width(), self.height(),
                                     Qt.KeepAspectRatio,Qt.FastTransformation))
```

[image]

Comment: as for me it is enough fluid. If you need more then maybe you should use faster language - C/C++.

Comment: @furas Do you see that the video return takes time to resize, unlike the lower block with the sliders which is instantaneous?

Comment: as for me video is resized fast enough.

Comment: What does this sentence mean: _I tried thanks to resize event not to make it dependent on this timer, and since it's more fluid, but still not instantaneous_?

Comment: Before this line depended on the updating of the camera image, ie every 20 milliseconds, with this definition, it no longer depends on that, but still does not solve the problem : `self.setPixmap(self.p.scaled(self.width(), self.height(),
                                     Qt.KeepAspectRatio,Qt.FastTransformation))`

Comment: If you put a simple image without a camera input - do you have the same effect? Does the laggind depend on the image resolution/size? Will smaller image size lead to less lagging? I just want to make clear if the transformation task is just heavy or there is an another problem.

Comment: @Vasilij Yes, also with an image, so without use a timer, it not depend on the image size.

Comment: Made an MVP for myself with some widgets and a QLabel with image. Scaling smoothly a 3MB picture(4160x3120) takes about 20 ms. And I got no lagging while scaling. But this is not the point - I would not use a setPixmap at all. I would either use QLabel's setPicture and draw my image on it or draw directly on a QWidget with a QPainter by overriding PaintEvent. This would give much more control.

Comment: @Vasilij How to create a QPicture with a Pixmap ?

Comment: I created a sample repo https://github.com/cxdevel/image_resize  You can use both methods setImage and setPixmap, just uncomment the code. Also, there is a duration estimation code there. But beware QPainter may be slow. Disclaimer: the code is sample only - not production ready at all)))  Also, check out these topics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297299/image-not-displaying-using-qpainter-drawimage and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930405/qpainterdrawimage-glitches-in-qt-5-10

Comment: Actually, i just use setPixmap, why use Qpainter + setPixmap can fix the problem ?

Comment: I do not think that QPainter alone would solve the problem. But it will give you the flexibility. You will have 3 distinct problems: 1. Scaling of a QWidget-based class (QLabel in your case) performed by Qt layout which should be smooth. If it is not, then there is a problem somewhere else. 2. Scaling your image. 3. Drawing the image with QPainter. I updated the repo with QWidget based example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, this solution would help. The key difference is that the image is updated on paintEvent, not on resizeEvent. The code is C++ not Python, but I am sure you get the idea.

```
#ifndef IMAGEWIDGET_H
#define IMAGEWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>

class ImageWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ImageWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {}
    void setImage(const QString &path) {
        m_image.load(path);
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override {
        QPainter painter(this);
        auto scaled = m_image.scaled(width(), height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
        painter.drawImage(0,0, scaled);
        painter.end();
    }

private:
    QImage m_image;
};

#endif // IMAGEWIDGET_H
```

Comment: Thanks, the paintEvent solution work, now i have another problem, how to resize the parent (Qlabel) with the children (Image), before with KeepAspectRatio and setScaledContents, it work almost perfectly, but now, setScaledContents not work, and have a blank space with KeepAspectRatio, and IgnoreAspectRatio is not as good as KeepAspectRatio+setScaledContents solution

Comment: You want your QLabel to be scaled with the same aspect ratio as the image inside, right? So that image fits perfectly inside it?

Comment: Well, this is a difficult question. And it seems the correct answer is a custom layout. You can consider this: https://gist.github.com/pavel-perina/1324ff064aedede0e01311aab315f83d  Dealing with resizeEvent is not the best solution as it may lead to infinite loops. It seems that putting any code that can change widget size in the resizeEvent is a bad idea. SizeHints are not of any use as well, because they either constraint max/min sizes or called only once. WidthForHeight works only for GraphicalWidgets. So, the only correct solution left is a custom layout. It seems this is the designed way.